# how to update a table values based on the table values in update statement?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database

I am using mqsql for db and connect the db from C#.Now i want to update a table field by adding the **table field + my current value**.

I have done like,

first i get the field using select statement and then add my current value to the existing value.Finally update the table by set the new value to table field...

So, Is there any way to do it in `UPDATE` statement without using `SELECT` statement?

Please guide me to get out of this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it the same table, you can `UPDATE` it directly and use the `WHERE` clause to do this for the field value only that you want, instead of the `SELECT`.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE Tablename
SET Somefield = Somefield + 'Some value'
WHERE SomeField = 'Some other value';
```

**Note that:** Also There is no need to get the field value first then add your current value to the existing value and finally do the update, you can *however*, do this directly using: `SET Somefield = Somefield + 'Some value'`.

Comment: @i want to cast someField into int and then add into my integer variable

Comment: @Saravanan What is the data type of this field `SomeField`? if it is an integer you have to insure that the `some value` added to it is an integer and there is no  need to cast it to an integer. Why do you want to cast it then? Also try to update your question with the table structure and some sample data and what you want exactly to do. This will be very helpful. Thanks.